# How to include hmac message in the request message in custom HttpClientHandler

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am implementing HMAC authentication in my web api. I have written a custom `HttpClientHandler` to implement this. I got my hmac message and now I want to include the message as one the parameter in the jsonobject which I send in the `HttpClient`. Please find below the code sample i use

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient(new CustomHttpClientHandler());
var message = client.PostAsJsonAsync(route, content);
```

The content has a property called "Hmac" and now I want to set the value to this field in the custom HttpClientHandler.

Can anyone help how to achieve this?